# Optimizing Client Server Application Using Local DB?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server, client-server

I've got a client/server application written in C# using WPF.  The database on the server is getting quite large and the application has to load much of it's data (let's not debate that part of it...just trust me on that and take it for what it is).  I could instead pull the data as needed on demand, however that creates performance issues due to the constant querying back and forth with the remote db.

What would be great though, is if on application start I could pull down the data I need to the client and store it in a locally running database.  The application then queries the local database, rather than the remote server database.  In this way, the application keeps a low memory footprint, but still has quick access to the data since it's local.

Is it possible to use SQL Server Express or LocalDB in this manner?  i.e. letting them run on the client machines, and syncing with the server database on application start?  If so, would this be a recommended or not-recommended use of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out MS Sync Framework if you haven't already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx  There's a steep learning curve but it is designed for these kinds of scenarios.

The app can pull down new/updated data to the local database on startup or whenever required.  This is helpful for performance or when the network connection may be unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SQL Lite

[SQL LITE](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

[SQL LITE Features](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/features.wiki)

Comment: Interesting.  Seems better than SQL Express for these purposes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not think about this the other way around and rather than pushing additional concerns into your client just think about putting a thin layer in front of your database?

If you were to use a thin NoSQL based layer (MongoDB or CouchDB being most popular) you could just cache your objects within there so the load is taken off your database and pushed onto the cache, you also then get the ability to scale your cache horizontally across other boxes if you wanted.

I know this kinda goes against the "Using Local DB" part of your question, but I didn't want to ignore the fact that you could solve your problem without touching the client (maybe a few connection string changes but your models would stay the same).

Comment: Interesting idea and I would definitely be interested in this approach.  I've been researching it since you posted it.  My main concern is really the level of effort that would be required to add mongo-db as a middle-man.  At first it seemed not so bad, but now it's looking like it might be greater than first anticipated.  Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Well you can make it as simple or complex as you need to, as Mongo for example just stores your objects as is (the serialization and underlying transport is done for you) you just care about is saving and retrieving objects. Which generally you would use a web service of some kinda to expose the data, it may not be a direct match for what you need but it can go a long way to spreading the load of read queries providing its always simple POCO requests and not complex queries etc, which are another design problem for a different discussion.